# How to Create Python virtual environment inside an USB Flash

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualenv

I am running ubuntu 18.04.1 in virtual box, on windows 10. The Ubuntu is running 2.7 version python. The USB stick is mounted to the path `/opt/ext_usb/yyyy`. When I tried executing the command `virtualenv my-env-name --no-site-packages` , I am getting the following error.

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /opt/ext_usb/jpr_lamp/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /opt/ext_usb/jpr_lamp/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 724, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 946, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1417, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I would like to know why the permission is denied when creating python virtual environment inside an USB stick. Is it because the ubuntu is running in VM and USB is shared between the windows. Please Help !

Note:
I have tried creating symlink on USB stick using `ln -s /usr/bin/python /sampe/path/inUsb` and failed to create the symbolic link.

Is this the actual cause of the issue? If so, how to get rid of the issue. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comment @wholevinski

The USB stick that I have used has Fat32 file system and it won't support symbolic links. Able to create the symlinks after changing the file system from fat32 to NTFS. Now I am able to create python virtual environment in an USB flash.